get all xml attributes from a node using xlst 1.0 transformation
I have the following xml and i would like to only filter the attributes of node "A" using XLST version 1.0 transformation
<A a_1="a1" a_2="a2"/>
<B>
 <C>
    hello
 </C>
</B>

I can use the following XLST transformation, but i'm looking if there is a way to get all the attributes without going one by one
<A a_1="{A/@a_1}" a_2="{A/@a_2}">

The output response would look like
<A a_1="a1" a_2="a2">


Please edit you question and add an example of the XML input, your current stylesheet and the expected output - all as code, not pictures.

In your example, the XPath expression /A/@* will select all attributes of the root A element. It's not clear what you want to do with this selection.

This is an example of only 2 attributes, i would like to know if there is a xlst transformation so it can take all the attributes of a node. For example, if the node A has 200 attributes

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

As I said, you can use @* to select all the attributes of the context node. Your stylesheet is incomplete and so it seems is your output, so it's hard to say exactly what your code should look like. Probably just <A><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/></A>.

@michael.hor257k, I'm trying to get the attributes of node "A". The code you are providing is to get the child elements of node "A". In the example, node "A" doesn't have child elements

All ##1-3 are missing.

XSLT is very much sensitive to context. With a well-formed input such as:
<A a_1="a1" a_2="a2">
  <B>
    <C>
    hello
 </C>
  </B>
</A>

you can use this stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to get:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A a_1="a1" a_2="a2"/>


Thanks for the useful answer. I was able to run with this code and I only change the following part. <xsl:copy-of select="A"/>

That will do a lot more than what you asked for.
